# Knockout mapping data from ajax post vs Static data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've encounted a strange problem with Ko mapping.
I use this piece of code:

```
var PList = [{ "Region": { "RegionName": "SomeRegion" }, "CDetails": {}, "Category": { "Name": "SomeCategory" }, "PSource": 1, "PDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"}];

var PViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(search('someSearch', 'True'));
var PViewModel2 = ko.mapping.fromJS(PostList);

function search(queryString, isFirst) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: { 'searchQuery': queryString },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (dt) {
            if (isFirst != 'True') {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(dt, PostsViewModel);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    });
};
```

Strangely I see 2 outcomes:

1. When I go to PViewModel (the one populated by ajax) I see it as `undefined`
2. When I go to PViewModel2 (the one with static data) I can see the objects as expected

*The static data of PViewModel2 is just a copy of the data returned by the ajax post.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know why is this so? And how to fix it?
2. Furthermore, is the `if (isFirst != 'True')` clause the right way to init the ko view model?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Include all more of your scripts so we can see model structures and the bindings

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an asynchronous operation (an Ajax request). *These operations do not have return values.* Therefore, this can never work:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(search('someSearch', 'True'));
```

That's what the `success` callback is for. Incoming data can only be handled there.

```
function search(queryString, targetObservable) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: { 'searchQuery': queryString },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (dt) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(dt, targetObservable);
        }
    });
};

search('someSearch', PostsViewModel);
```